# The type is declared but I can't use it. Why?

Tags: typescript

I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bson) `bson` library and [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/bson) declaration. The library has a method `serialize():Buffer` which returns a `Buffer`. When I call the code like this:

```
let data:Buffer = this.serializer.serialize();
```

everything works fine - I can see the `data` in debugger, inspect its fields.

But when I'm trying to create an instance of the `Buffer` directly:

```
let buf:Buffer = new Buffer(10);
```

I'm getting a runtime error - `ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`. Why is that and how to fix?

Comment: Did you import the declaration file to your project?

Comment: In your question you referred to 2 declaration files, the @types will install the (almost) same declaration file in from DefinitelyTyped repo

Comment: @M98 I imported declarations that marked as `export` in `*.d.ts` files. But this particular type (`Buffer`) is not exported. It's declared this way: `interface Buffer extends NodeBuffer { }; declare var Buffer: {...}`. I don't know what this `declare var` means.

Comment: Could you please share how you imported the declaration file? If you installed the declaring file using @types, then you should import the index.d.ts which are in types directory in node_modules

Comment: `import {BSON} from "bson";`. And I can use the library for serializing the messages. Now I want to deserialize and I need to create a buffer for that.

Comment: @nikitablack `declare var Foo` tells TypeScript "Foo exists, don't bother that you can't see it yet". Useful if you, for instance, put something in `window` or `global` somewhere inside a JS file without any typings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define names in typescript they may be defined in the *variable declaration space* or the *type declaration space* (or both).

The variable declaration space is where all the Javascript stuff happens: so when you do `let foo: Buffer = [1, 2];` that defines `foo` as a variable and the Javascript code that is output will also contain `foo`.

The type declaration space is where all the type related stuff happens, and none of that survives through to the Javascript.

If you define a `class` that adds a name to both variable declaration space and type declaration space, but if you define an `interface` that only adds a name to the type declaration space. To instantiate a variable you need to have a constructor function you can call, but if you just have a type there's nothing you can use.

```
interface Buffer extends NodeBuffer { };
```

So this first declaration provides the type information. It means the compiler and your editor can do type checking and tell you if you try to access attributes that don't exist. But that is all in the type declaration space, it doesn't add anything to the variable declaration space: there is nothing about `Buffer` in the output Javascript.

```
declare var Buffer: {...}
```

This is what is known as an ambient declaration: it says that somewhere there is some Javascript which has created a global variable called `Buffer` with this type. The compiler will believe that and won't complain if you try to use `Buffer`, but you are responsible for ensuring that whatever Javascript would create the variable is included in your page.

So the `ReferenceError` happens because there's a promise to the compiler that `Buffer` will be around at runtime, but the Javascript that would have created the `Buffer` variable hasn't been included.

See https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html for more description of *variable declaration space* and *type declaration space*.

Edit: I don't know `bson` at all, but the documentation doesn't actually say you can create a `Buffer` directly. So the fact you can successfully serialise something implies to me that it's the type library at fault when it claims there should be a global `Buffer` in the namespace. I think it should only be giving you the interface and you can't expect to instantiate something if all you have is an interface.

Comment: Sorry, I came from strictly typed languages and I simply can't wrap my head around. How did that happen that I can access `Buffer` through calling a method (`serializer.serialize()` in my case), but can't create it directly? And what should I do to make it available?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can make it available. See edit at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just because there's typings for something does not mean it must exist when transpiled into JavaScript. For example:

```
type Buffer = ArrayBuffer | Array<any>;

let foo: Buffer = [1, 2]; // OK

new Buffer(); // Error
```

(You may [test it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Buffer%20%3D%20ArrayBuffer%20%7C%20Array%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%3A%20Buffer%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Valid%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Buffer()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error))

In your case, the typings file states, that `serialize` returns

> @return {Buffer} returns a TypedArray or Array depending on what your browser supports

Comment: But I can see `Buffer` definition in source files - with constructor, members. So I assume it's not just a type alias.

Comment: And in fact I have a different error - runtime in opposite to compile time `'Buffer' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` from your example.

Comment: @nikitablack As far as I can see, this library imports Buffer as `var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;` (https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/1.0-branch/lib/bson/binary.js, line 8 - 10) but I can't see any exports of that variable. You may try to import it yourself.

Comment: I think it's not a problem with imports because the code compiles. It can't find the definition in runtime. So I need somehow to tell where to search.

Comment: As a comment on your question you said there's a `declare var Buffer`. I answered on that one: `declare var` means "TypeScript, don't bother if you can't find the variable, it does exist". TypeScript will trust you and just transpile the code into JavaScript. Eventually, this does not mean it really exists (or it may in a specific scope and not in an other).